# Compass Heading on DJI UX SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

Ive installed and run the dji ux sdk for android. Sdk registration success and able to access all three tab ( normal , modified n map view)

My question would be how to display compass.getheading() value to the main screen?

My understanding would be both in java n xml needed to be code.

Xml part is done.

Only the java part im pretty confuse.

Any help is highly appreciated.

[link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MKaJ.jpg)

Comment: try to ask specific programming question. The question you ask does not provide enough for others to provide a solution. We dont know what you dont know.  for DJI GO APP it is the little triangle that represent the heading. The rotation of the triangle is corresponding to the yaw angle. You dont know how to display this pattern or what?

Comment: Thank you for replying, basically the triangle didnt provide numerical value of the azimuth. What im trying to do is basically to get azimuth display in numerical value ie

Azimuth / bearing: 123.4°

Comment: public double getHeading ()
Represents the heading in degrees. 
True North is 0 degrees heading, positive heading is East of North(clockwise), negative heading is West of North(counterclockwise) and heading bounds are [-180, 180]. It is one of the commonly used terms in robotics. You can add both side with 180 so that it will appear to be like other compass apps display in Azimuth

Comment: Thank Dr Yuan, 

And whats the method to call the value?

Flightcontroller.Compass.getHeading? 

Thank you.

Comment: compass.getHeading()     see https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/blob/master/Sample%20Code/app/src/main/java/com/dji/sdk/sample/demo/flightcontroller/CompassCalibrationView.java

Comment: Each time i pull the data, it will crash the apps. 

any tips on if loop to check if the data is ready?

Thanks in advance Dr.

Comment: ModuleVerificationUtil.isCompassAvailable()